# Android Action Bar Customization vs A Custom View

Tags: android

If I want a customized action bar, should I implement the customization on the action bar or should I just use a custom view instead of an action bar. Navigation bar in iOS has a specific animation but as far as I understand, action bar in Android does not have anything speacial associated with it. So would it be more flexible and easier to implement it as just a view?

Answer (score 0):

Once in a while I was thinking like this created a app with custom view as a action bar but when we want to use custom view we have to declare everytime  in every activity which may cost more time .

Pros : You can create your action bar as per your wish can animate,change design,change UI etc.

Cons : cost more time on development .

Comment: You don't have to create it for each activity. You can create a base activity and extend that activity again and again. You can even create a generic method that returns a `View` and have few parameters in this method. For example, `String` for name, `int` for left icon image, `int` for right icon image and two `OnClickListener` for those buttons.